# How to convert Javascript version encode abi to Python version?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

I want to convert encode abi from Javascript version to Python version, but there is more `0` at the end of Python version, how to make it same as Javascript version? I have tries `bytes32`, `b''` and `b'0x'` in Python version but didn't work.

Javascript version:

```js
import { defaultAbiCoder } from '@ethersproject/abi'
defaultAbiCoder.encode(
      ['uint256', 'bytes'],
      [9999999999999, '0x']
)
// 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009184e729fff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Python version:

```py
from eth_abi import encode_abi
encode_abi(
        ['uint256', 'bytes'],
        [9999999999999, bytes(0)]
)
# 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009184e729fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: You can find Python eth-abi documentation here: https://eth-abi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Did you try `b''`? In javascript `'0x'` is an empty bytes array.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing different output because the output is in different data type.

For python, it is in: `hex` (`your_data.hex()`)

For javascript it is in: `string`

Let me show you the code output from my tests on your code:

**Python:**

```
from eth_abi import encode_abi

base = encode_abi(
        ['uint256', 'bytes'],
        [9999999999999, bytes(0)]
)

print(type(base))
print(base.hex())
```

This will output:

```
<class 'bytes'>
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009184e729fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**JavaScript:**

import { defaultAbiCoder }

```
from '@ethersproject/abi'

let base = defaultAbiCoder.encode(
      ['uint256', 'bytes'],
      [9999999999999, '0x']
)

console.log(typeof((base)))
console.log(base)
```

The output will be:

```
string
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009184e729fff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I hope it helps you proceed with this problem.

Comment: "You are seeing different output because the output is in different data type.". No. You didn't read the question "there are more 0 in the python version". I want the output of python same as Javascript. Your python output is same as mine.